# How to prevent my site form being parsed?

Tags: php, html, css, parsing, dom

Are there any tips or tricks to prevent my site (let's say it's pure HTML and CSS) from being parsed? How can I protect my site from things like [f.ex](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

Maybe messing around with the DOM would help? Any ideas?

Comment: If a browser can't parse it, it can't display it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: make screenshots of you pages and use them as website :)

Comment: @Pull Up you could make it accessible only to authenticated users (htaccess password protected, maybe, if you don't want to use any dynamic language), just leave a login "freely-parsable" page and let the rest be only for trusted users...Who can then parse it, of course.

Comment: @meo This is the funniest yet only way to accomplish what he wants. You beat me to it.

Answer (score 7):

You can't "prevent your site form from being parsed". If your HTML page was not parsable, the visitor could not read it with their browser. You could *obfuscate* your page using Javascript and generate the HTML using it, but that's easily circumvented.

If your goal is "protecting" your HTML source, keep the page on your notebook / tablet / smartphone and show it to others without making the page available on the Internet. In that way, users cannot see your HTML source nor parse it. Still, any form of HTML source protection is questionable. Another way to hide your HTML is by taking a picture of your page, but that has some disadvantages like increase of file size and inability for screen readers to read your page.

DOM stands for Document Object Model and is in short an easy way to access your HTML elements. It's no magic and cannot help you from preventing the form being parsed. Again, if the browser cannot parse it, the user won't see it either.

Comment: I've never come across an obfuscator that couldn't be defeated. As @meo mentions, to make it utterly *difficult* (note, not impossible), simply switch to another medium (Flash, image, PDF, custom format?). I really doubt it's worth it, though, for what the content is worth.

Comment: Yeah, you're sure. I got this question on one of my interviews and I was confused. I thought, that maybe there some "magic" tricks to achive this... I don't know what interviewer had in his mind then. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old, but just in case, Yes you actually can prevent (not a rock solid answer) your site from being parsed if you check for the browser headers, before you display anything. In PHP for example (I tested it myself)

```
$arraySet = array();
$arraySet =apache_request_headers();

if($arraySet['User-Agent']){

 // place your code or html here if you dont want it to be accessed via fopen, fread etc.
}
```

if accessed directly, I can see/read the website content, but If via `file_get_contents()`, nothing shows up in the response.

Of course, this way, you would most probably prevent web crawlers among other ...